# How to create a specific json format from dataframe with loop

Tags: python, json, pandas

I like to transform a dataframe to a pre-format json to make a call in an API
my dataframe looks like :

```
;First Name;Name;Country;Email
0;Paul;TRUC;FR;test@gmail,com
1;Henry;DEFAULT;US;test1@gmail.com
2;John;TEMP;GB;test2@gmail.com
```

I expect :

```
{"Adresse": [
    {
        "_ActionFlag": "create",
        "Id": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx",
        "Pays": "FR"
    },
 "Individu": [
     {
         "_ActionFlag": "create",
         "Id": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx",
         "First Name": "Paul",
         "Name": "TRUC",
         "Email": "test@gmail.com"
     },
     {
         "_ActionFlag": "create",
         "Id": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx",
         "First Name": "Henry",
         "Name": "DEFAULT",
         "Email": "test1@gmail.com"
     },
     {
         "_ActionFlag": "create",
         "Id": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx",
         "First Name": "John",
         "Name": "TEMP",
         "Email": "test2@gmail.com"
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: see here https://datatofish.com/export-pandas-dataframe-json/

Comment: Is it a typo or do you *really* want to ignore the `Country` field from the csv file?

Comment: Indeed, Country field is Pays field

Answer (score 0):

Read the CSV into DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'data/user.csv', header='infer', sep=';')
```

DataFrame looks like:

```
Id  First Name  Name    Country Email
0   Paul        TRUC    FR      test@gmail,com
1   Henry       DEFAULT US      test1@gmail.com
2   John        TEMP    GB      test2@gmail.com
```

Convert DataFrame into json:

```
json = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

JSON looks like:

```
'[{"Id":0,"First Name":"Paul","Name":"TRUC","Country":"FR","Email":"test@gmail,com"},{"Id":1,"First Name":"Henry","Name":"DEFAULT","Country":"US","Email":"test1@gmail.com"},{"Id":2,"First Name":"John","Name":"TEMP","Country":"GB","Email":"test2@gmail.com"}]'
```

See the running sample here:

- [Python Sample](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference/blob/master/datascience/stack/57062202-pandas-csv-to-json.py)
- [Jupyter Notebook Sample](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference/blob/master/datascience/stack/57062202-pandas-csv-to-json.ipynb)